# System.Diagnostics Debug Class Missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm trying to write some debug output to the output window using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine().  AFAIK, the only requirement to be able to use the System.Diagnostics class is to add the System namespace (which is there by default).  I have one project where I can use the Debug class, as shown below:

[image: With Debug]

But my current project doesn't show the debug class and I'm confused:

[image: Debug Missing]

Suggestions?

EDIT:  This was the problem - I initially added my external class file as a 'Solution Item' and it placed it to the top of the solution in a folder.  When the program didn't compile because my reference on Form1 to the namespace failed, I simply dragged the class file from the solution folder to the program folder (for lack of a better description).  It was this duplication and versioning mismatch that was my problem.  As soon as I removed the reference to the 'Solution Item', my breakpoints were working again and the System.Diagnostics.Debug class was available in my class file.

[image: Debug Class Issue Fixed]

Answer (score 5):

The `Debug` class is supported in all profiles and version of the .Net framework.  The most likely cause of this not showing up in Intellisense are ...

1. Missing reference to System.dll where `Debug` lives
2. Intellisense bug (possible, but unlikely here)

The most likely cause is #1.  Can you make sure you have the appropriate reference?

Comment: The reference to System.dll is created automatically by VS when you begin a new project (which I did) rather than just a new class file.  I verified that the reference is there, and the DLL version is the same for the project that is working, and the one that is not.  I'm going to try saving, closing, then re-opening my project to see if intellisense picks it up.

Comment: @spickles have you tried actually compiling the reference to `Debug`?  This will tell you if it's an intellisense error

Comment: forgive me if I don't understand how to compile a reference specifically.  When I compile/build and run my application, I don't get any errors.  I also was able to find System.Diagnostics.Debug in the object browser by right-clicking the System.dll and selecting 'View in Object Browser'.  That would tell me that the System.dll file is good?

Comment: @spickles I meant just add a `Debug.WriteLine("");` statement to your code, compile and see if it works.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I did that.  I included 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test"), and while intellisense didn't underline it as being an invalid line of code, it nonetheless did not output to the console.

Comment: @spickles whether or not it outputs is different than if it compiled.  If it compiled then it indicates that intellisense is failing to pick it up even though it's there.

Comment: I'm trying to write to the output window from within my class file, which is a separate namespace from the main form.  The main form has access to my classes since I've added the reference.  This is where it doesn't work.  It does work from the main form.  Is this not a common practice?  I'm simply writing to the output window as part of my try/catch block, so it doesn't seem unusual to me.

Comment: @spickles if it copmiles but doesn't output then most likely you don't have `DEBUG` or `TRACE` defined in that particular project

Comment: Found the problem - my project was building with both an item included AND a reference included, both pointing to my separate class file.  I must have added it to the project incorrectly.  Removing the duplicate and just leaving the reference worked.

Comment: OP edited to reflect the solution to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
global::System.Diagnostics.Debug
```